# Any VST for removing harmonic content from audio?

Tags: windows, music, audio, music-production

I wonder if there are any VSTs which remove automatically the main harmonic content from an audio source.

For example, if I have a simple sine wave, this hypothetical software/device would return absolutely nothing, silence.

If the sine wave has been previously distorted a bit, then this device would return at least some of the noise produced by the distortion, omitting the frequency of the original sine wave.

What I wish is a tool that does not only automatically removes one single frequency, but a set of frequencies that might be harmonically related. For example, passing a pure sawtooth through the device would also return silence.

I think that a device like this has to exist already. Any pointers?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you care about GUI or CLI? what OS? what pricing is acceptable? How about solutions that require some coding (like python or PHP or somthing) - not that I know of any but just out to get more information about your desired tool.

Comment: @NickWilde : thanks for the suggestions. Why do you mention CLI? In what sense this might be related to a VST? I did not set initially the OS because I am interested in knowing if something exists, even if it's not compatible with my OS (which is Windows, by the way).

Comment: I'm not really familiar with VST but I would *guess* that CLI and GUI options would both be possible; assuming that to be the case I know that some people are congenitally averse to CLI so I like to check that.

Comment: @NickWilde : no. A VST is a plugin for music production software. It does not have a CLI in the traditional sense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is possible to indicate/mark a region which has only/mainly the noise, and not other audio of interest. In that case, one could use the [Noise Reduction tool in Audacity](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/noise_reduction.html) for this. This is a type of spectral subtraction noise reducer, so it works well for spectral content that is nearly constant over time.